# How do I change the display name (or create script) of MSI App in Appwiz.cpl

Tags: windows-registry, rename, appwiz.cpl

Objective, How to create a script/command to change the unique product name of an application to display differently in appwiz.cpl Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products*
I want it too display as SupportMeNow.net

[ScreenConnect Client (e9870228b647f471)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ciwcx.png)

This is what appears by default in appwiz. ScreenConnect Client (e9870228b647f471)

[Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{E2F17190-E91D-44C4-86FF-D3C6743BDC55}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Loe.png)

This is where I found the MSI uninstall String. I attempted to change "Display Name" to SupportMeNow.net and it still showed as ScreenConnect Client (e9870228b647f471) in appwiz.cpl,

Then I decided to change at the product ID.

[Product ID/Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lXGW.png)

I changed Product Name = Supportmenow.net and it successfully changed in Appwiz.cpl

[Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjtzR.png)

So my question is, How can I create a script/export and deploy it to all my machines to change the Product Name on all my machines, I have end point management and can push any command/powershell script. I just need to know how I can set a variable to detect the unique product ID to change Product Name. I hope this makes sense, If not feel free to respond to me and I will do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Use the
[reg add command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add).

Something like:

```
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\AF35113BF7EC493468E2FA5706BA2A1B /v ProductName /d "SupportMeNow.net"
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm already aware of the Reg Add command, I'm wondering how I can use it to identify the unique product path for the 1000+ machines it is already deployed on.

Comment: Isn't this value always at the same place in the registry? Aren't all the computers in a domain?